# AWS CDK API Gateway enable Cors

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, api-gateway

I am trying to enable Cors for AWS API Gateway using cdk and I seem to be doing everything correctly but the react front end still gives cors error. My cdk code looks like this. Pasting the same url in the chrome browser works. I am using AWS version 1.90 for lambda , api gateway etc and cannot upgrade.

```
    var apiBase = new RestApiBase(this, `my-${this.resourcePrefix}-api`, {
      apiSubDomain: `${this.appName}`,
      stage: this.stage,
    });

    const corsOptions = {
      allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
      allowHeaders: Cors.DEFAULT_HEADERS,
      allowMethods: Cors.ALL_METHODS,
    };


    // create a lambda function in the VPC with SQL Server access
    const sqlConstruct = new VpcSqlLambda(this, "my-api-lambda", {
      resourceSlashPrefix: this.resourceSlashPrefix,
      dbServerParamValue: process.env.DBSERVER ?? "xx.xx.xx.xx",
      dbNameParamValue: process.env.DBSERVER ?? "mydbname",
      dbUsernameParamValue: process.env.DBSERVER ?? "user",
     
    });

apiBase.AddLambdaIntegration(
      sqlConstruct.lambda,
      {
        resource: "getList",
        method: "GET",
        options: {
          defaultCorsPreflightOptions: corsOptions,
          integrationResponses: [
            {
              statusCode: "200",
              responseParameters: {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
                  "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'",
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'",
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":
                  "'false'",
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods":
                  "'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST'",
                "method.response.body.Content-Type": "'application/json'",
                "method.response.body.Models": "'Empty'",
              },
            },
          ],
          passthroughBehavior: apigw.PassthroughBehavior.NEVER,
          requestTemplates: {
            "application/json": '{"statusCode": 200}',
          },
          methodResponses: [
            {
              statusCode: "200",
              responseParameters: {
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers": true,
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods": true,
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
                "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      }
    );
```

It does not work. Normal postman calls work and pasting the url in the browser works but React gives cors error.

Manually enabling cors gives the following error:

[image]

[image]

Options integrations setup
[image]

Options Message response
[image]

Get method response header
[image]

Comment: Also, I suggest you check out this _excellent_ example of an API Gateway + Lambda + DynamoDB + SQS + SES + ...... _all_ managed using the CDK: https://github.com/davidtucker/ps-serverless-app

Comment: You should be using [`RestApi`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.RestApi.html) (has more features) rather than [`RestApiBase`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.RestApiBase.html) (a base class).  The former supports CORS configuration while the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using API Gateway v1 REST APIs, take a look at the [CORS documentation and examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigateway/README.html?highlight=addcorspreflight#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors) for API Gateway v1 REST APIs.

To enable CORS for your REST API, you must first use `RestApiBase` instead of `RestApi`, and then add the following configuration to the `RestApi` (along with `apiSubDomain`, etc.)

```js
defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
    allowOrigins: apigateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
    allowMethods: apigateway.Cors.ALL_METHODS
}
```

Comment: Glad this helped @bex! Consider upvoting my answer in addition to accepting it.