# Typescript - AWS CDK Enable CORS

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Part of my cdk project is a Websocket that gets output of a StepFunction which is triggered by a `POST` Request. This whole workflow works in the aws console just as postman.

But if I try it over the frontend I receive a CORS error:

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have set up my CORS options like this:

```
const api = new apigw.RestApi(this, `${props.devName}BookingApi`, { 
            // set up CORS            
            defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
                allowHeaders: [
                    'Content-Type',
                    'X-Amz-Date',
                    'Authorization',
                    'X-Api-Key',
                    'X-Amz-Security-Token'
                  ],
                  statusCode: 200,
                  allowMethods: ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
                  allowCredentials: true,
                  allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS           
            },
            deploy: true
        });
```

If I manually enable CORS in the AWS console I do not receive a CORS error from the frontend. The CORS options in the code are the same as the ones I put in manually.
Also strange is, that eventhough I get the CORS error from the frontend, the WebSocket posts the output of the StepFunction.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249114/aws-cdk-api-gateway-enable-cors) but the solution does not work for me.

edit1: added Errormessage

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution!

The setup was fine like this. I was missing this part in the `apigw.AWSIntegration` options:

```
integrationResponses: [
                    {
                      responseParameters: {
                        'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "'*'",
                      },
                      responseTemplates: {
                        'application/json': JSON.stringify({
                          message: '$util.parseJson($input.body)',
                          state: 'ok',
                        }),
                      },
                      statusCode: '200',
```

and also

```
methodResponses: [{ 
            statusCode: '200',
            // important for CORS
            responseParameters: {
                'method.response.header.Content-Type': true,
                'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
                'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
            }
        }]
```

in `.addMethod`

edit1: This [link](https://dev.to/aws-builders/your-complete-api-gateway-and-cors-guide-11jb#restapi-service-integrations) helped me to find the solution

edit2: updated body of `methodResponses`:

Comment: This is almost an answer: in original question you were using `apigw.RestApi` so where does the `apigw.AWSIntegration` come from?

Comment: When you create your `.addMethod` you can add an `apigw.AWSIntegration` check this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway-readme.html